# Avoid picking rows from joined table and use it only to get column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

`dbo.MatchDate(@Date)` :An inline TVF that returns results from `dbo.Patients` table .The inline TVF returns these columns : `RowId` and `Percentmatch`  .

I have this query so far:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)
SELECT RowNumber, d.PercentMatch, @constVal, d.PercentMatch * @constVal
from dbo.MatchDate(@Date) d inner join dbo.Patients p 
on d.RowNumber = p.RowId 
inner join dbo.ResultsStored rs on rs.RowId = d.RowNumber 
where p.ModifiedAt > rs.ModifiedAt
```

I needed to check if `ModifiedAt` value of rows returned by `dbo.MatchDate(@Date)` function from `dbo.Patients` table is greater than `ModifiedAt` of rows in `ResultsStored` table with `RowId's` same as returned by `dbo.MatchDate(@Date)`. Since `dbo.MatchDate(@Date)` returns only `RowId` and `PercentMatch`, to get `ModifiedAt` of those rows, I joined `Patients` table on `RowId` column.
Then for comparison sake, to get `ModifiedAt` from `ResultsStored` table, I joined it further with `dbo.ResultsStored` on `RowId` column only.

**Problem :** It results in duplicated rows inserted i.e not only I am getting rows from `dbo.MatchDate(@Date)` but also from `dbo.ResultsStored` table which was not at all intended. `dbo.ResultsStored` was only to check the `ModifiedAt` value for same `row id's`.

How I may modify above query to avoid this duplication of rows in `#Temp2` because of `dbo.ResultsStored` table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `EXISTS` to check  what you want:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)
SELECT RowNumber, d.PercentMatch, @constVal, d.PercentMatch * @constVal
FROM dbo.MatchDate(@Date) AS d
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM dbo.Patients AS p 
   INNER JOIN dbo.ResultsStored AS rs ON rs.RowId = d.RowNumber 
   WHERE (d.RowNumber = p.RowId) AND (p.ModifiedAt > rs.ModifiedAt) )
```

This will insert into `#Temp2` only records from `TVF`, provided that there is *at least one* record, with same `RowId`, from `dbo.Patients` with `ModifiedAt` greater than `ModifiedAt` of a corresponding record from `dbo.ResultsStored`.